# Display the serverTime from ASP.NET in four different time zones with JScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sharepoint, datetime

I am adding a custom header to a SharePoint master page and I would like to display the current time in four different time zones. However, I don't want to use the client's time as there is no way to know what time zone the client will be in, or if they have the correct time on their computer.

Ideally, the time should be displayed as follows:

Dallas: (UTC-6 w/ DST support)  Zulu: (UTC)  Iraq: (UTC+3)  Afghanistan: (UTC+4.5)

My problem is that I really don't know anything about ASP.NET, as I'm a PHP guy myself. So I need a way to pass the serverTime as a variable that JavaScript can use to perform calculations on to display the correct time zone.

**UPDATE:**

I need the clock to update as each second changes. So it is a live time instead of a static time.

**UPDATE 2:**

This is the code I'm using, any suggestions?

```
<script runat="server">
  Sub Page_Load(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal E As EventArgs)
  End Sub
  Public Function dtBase() As Double
  Dim d1 As Date = New Date(1970, 1, 1)
  Dim d2 As Date = Date.UtcNow
  Dim ts As TimeSpan = d2 - d1
  Return ts.TotalMilliseconds
  End Function
</script>

<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

var serverTime=<%=dtBase%>
var clientTime = new Date().getTime();
var milliDiff = serverTime - clientTime;

function tO(){ return new Date(); }

function tN(){ x=new Date(tO().getUTCFullYear(),tO().getUTCMonth(),tO().getUTCDate(),tO().getUTCHours(),tO().getUTCMinutes(),tO().getUTCSeconds()); x.setTime(x.getTime()+milliDiff); return x; }

function lZ(x){ return (x>9)?x:'0'+x; } 

// CST time (subtract 5 hours from UTC time)
// function dS(){ x=new Date(tN().getUTCFullYear(),tN().getUTCMonth(),tN().getUTCDate(),tN().getUTCHours(),tN().getUTCMinutes(),tN().getUTCSeconds()); x.setTime(x.getTime()-(5*3600000)); return x; } 
// CST time (subtract 6 hours from UTC time)        
function dS(){ x=new Date(tN().getUTCFullYear(),tN().getUTCMonth(),tN().getUTCDate(),tN().getUTCHours(),tN().getUTCMinutes(),tN().getUTCSeconds()); x.setTime(x.getTime()-(6*3600000)); return x; } 
function dallasT(){ document.getElementById('DALLAS').innerHTML=eval(dT); setTimeout('dallasT()',1000); } 
var dT="lZ(dS().getHours())+':'+lZ(dS().getMinutes())+':'+lZ(dS().getSeconds())";

// ZULU time (UTC time)
function zS(){ x=new Date(tN().getUTCFullYear(),tN().getUTCMonth(),tN().getUTCDate(),tN().getUTCHours(),tN().getUTCMinutes(),tN().getUTCSeconds()); x.setTime(x.getTime()); return x; } 
function zuluT(){ document.getElementById('ZULU').innerHTML=eval(zT); setTimeout('zuluT()',1000); } 
var zT="lZ(zS().getHours())+':'+lZ(zS().getMinutes())+':'+lZ(zS().getSeconds())";

// IRAQ time (add 3 hours to UTC time)
function iS(){ x=new Date(tN().getUTCFullYear(),tN().getUTCMonth(),tN().getUTCDate(),tN().getUTCHours(),tN().getUTCMinutes(),tN().getUTCSeconds()); x.setTime(x.getTime()+(3*3600000)); return x; } 
function iraqT(){ document.getElementById('IRAQ').innerHTML=eval(iT); setTimeout('iraqT()',1000); } 
var iT="lZ(iS().getHours())+':'+lZ(iS().getMinutes())+':'+lZ(iS().getSeconds())";

// AFGN time (add 4.5 hours to UTC time)
function aS(){ x=new Date(tN().getUTCFullYear(),tN().getUTCMonth(),tN().getUTCDate(),tN().getUTCHours(),tN().getUTCMinutes(),tN().getUTCSeconds()); x.setTime(x.getTime()+(4.5*3600000)); return x; } 
function afgnT(){ document.getElementById('AFGN').innerHTML=eval(aT); setTimeout('afgnT()',1000); } 
var aT="lZ(aS().getHours())+':'+lZ(aS().getMinutes())+':'+lZ(aS().getSeconds())";

</script>  
</head>
<body onload="zuluT();dallasT();iraqT();afgnT();">
<table>    
  <tr>
    <td>
      DALLAS: <span id="DALLAS">&nbsp;</span>
      ZULU: <span id="ZULU">&nbsp;</span>
      IRAQ: <span id="IRAQ">&nbsp;</span>
      AFGN: <span id="AFGN">&nbsp;</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**UPDATE 3:**

Still don't know if the code worked. My SharePoint server rejected the page for the code blocks. I have absolutely zero idea how to do code-behind. The JS works, but if the client's time is off, the site displays incorrect times. Really wish I could just code this in PHP. I'd be done a week ago. ;)

**UPDATE 4:**

This update is for anyone that stumbles across this in the future looking for the answer to the problem. The code above has been updated to work correctly. The only catch is that SharePoint disallows code by default, so to enable it, you have to modify the web.config file. The web.config file is usually in the root directory of the site. Inside that file (which is XML), you'll find a  tag. Somehwere inside of that, you should find , and inside of that, you should find . Inside of that tag, you want to add this:

```
<PageParserPath VirtualPath="/relative/path/to/your/file/here.aspx" CompilationMode="Always" AllowServerSideScript="true" />
```

I hope this helps y'all.

Comment: Many of us have felt this kind of pain dealing with Sharepoint. You might also try posting your question at [Sharepoint Overflow](http://www.sharepointoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The server time is simply...

```
Now()
```

You can set the value of the text property of a label control or the value property of a HiddenField control to Now() and then access it through Javascript in the OnLoad event.  You can also make a WebService in .Net that returns the server's current time (in JSON or XML) and call that through Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear why you want to do this in JavaScript. Or JScript. Please, whatever you do, **don't use JScript**. JScript has a lot of large corporations stuck in IE6 and therefore also Windows XP. (See the 4th comment [here](http://infrequently.org/2010/10/ie-8-is-the-new-ie-6/), among other sources.)

JavaScript runs on the client, so you are dealing with the time on the client's local machine. It is possible, but more difficult, to ascertain the client's time zone, and base your calculations on that.

However, if you you **use ASP.Net server-side code written in C# or VB**, you will automatically be using the server's local time.

Local time is UTC + the time zone offset for that location, + an offset (typically +1) for daylight saving time, if in effect.

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) explains how to get UTC (or Zulu) time in C# or VB. Basically, it is

```
DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
```

To add hours to that:

```
DateTime.Now.AddHours(3);
```

You can put a negative number (-3) to subtract hours.

You can combine those to adjust UTC:

```
DateTime.Now.AddHours(3).ToUniversalTime();
```

Comment: My mistake, I meant JavaScript, didn't realise I used an invalid abbreviation. It doesn't have to be JS, I just chose that because it seemed easiest. And I don't have access to upload anything to the server above the site directory. All I can modify is the default.master.